# Api or framework to get bounding box given one single point

Tags: node.js, coordinates, turfjs

Like the title says, I'm looking for a (free/GPL flavour licensed) api or node.js framework to get map coordinates for a bounding box X meters away given a single point.

For example; I have this point at long: 40.7666071 and lat: -74.2316785. And I want the bounding box surrounding that point at a 500 meter distance.

I've had a look at turfjs and leaflet for example, but it feels way too overkill for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself, my solution was to buffer the point and then calculate the bounding box of the buffer using Turf.js. Snippet is from an iteration in my code.

```
// Check if GeoJSON contains a single point in the layer
if (geojson.features.length == 1 && geojson.features[0].geometry.type == "Point") {
    features = turf.buffer(geojson, 50, {units: "feet"});
} else {
    features = layer.data;
}

// Calculate the bounding box of the geojson
bounding_boxes.push(turf.bboxPolygon(turf.bbox(features)));
```